# Google Maps issue with require optimizar

Tags: javascript, google-maps, requirejs-optimizer

I am loading google maps API with Requirejs, and it works fine but after using requirejs optimizer it raises error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`.

Here's my code

```
initMap = () ->
require ['async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true'], (maps) =>
  mapOptions = 
    center: {lat: 22.234376786, lng: 55.23243456456}
    zoom: 3
    scrollwheel: false
  debugger
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions)
```

And this is the requirejs [build.coffee](https://gist.github.com/NouranMahmoud/c4a216ea2695da6bf06a)

I've read almost all the questions here that are like mine but no one worked with me!.

Comment: Some partial solution, hope this gives you an idea: [**Link**](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/issues/45)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried their solutions but didn't work with me!